# Symmetries of a Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

I was wondering how many symmetries the polynomial $(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_3)$ has, and what they are. I got four:

(i) $(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_3)$

(ii) $(x_2-x_1)(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_3)$

(iii) $(x_1-x_3)(x_3-x_2)(x_1-x_2)$

(iv) $(x_3-x_2)(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)$

This is problem G. 2 in Pinter.

Comment: What is a "symmetry"?  For example, replacing $x_i$ by $x_i + c$ gives the same polynomial back—however, your ii), iii), and iv) are all not equal to the original polynomial (there is a sign change).  If you are looking at permutations of the variables, there is a homorphism $S_3 \to \{\pm 1\}$ with kernel a cyclic group of order $3$.  In particular, you have missed the cyclic permutations of the variables, which are somehow the basic symmetries of this expression.

Comment: I am not sure what the symmetries are exactly, but in Pinter, it says "the symmetries of a polynomial p are all the permutations of the subscripts which leave p unchanged."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition given, that we want the permutations of the variables leaving the polynomial unchanged, there are three—and all of your ii), iii), and iv) are incorrect, since they alter the sign.

A permutation of the variables will either give back the same polynomial, or alter the sign.  So there is a homomorphism $S_3 \to \{\pm 1\}$.  The kernel has order $3$—the identity permutation is a symmetry, and also $x_1\mapsto x_2\mapsto x_3$, and $x_1\mapsto x_3\mapsto x_2$ are symmetries.  Again, neither of these two are in your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think only 4; from what I understand you're simply multiplying terms with a minus sign.

To keep equality, you must have 2 negatives.

So we choose 2 of the 3 expressions to slap a minus sign on.

$\binom{3}{2}=3$. Adding the original expression, we have 4.

NB: I may be completely wrong as I have never heard of group theory in my life, I am only inferring from your question and the information provided.

Comment: Because I am so new to group theory and abstract, what do you mean by keeping equality with two negative signs?